# Woocommerce Subscription access from external php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscription

I have a Wordpress website with Woocommerce and Woocommerce Subscription plugins.

I need to write some PHP script that will check if a user has active subscription status.

From the database, I would like to get information: user id, status (if it's active - if payment was made and the subscription was renewed), end date of subscription...

The problem is that I don't even know where subscription info is saved?

Can somebody write me a snippet of code, that includes a query that will give me a list of users that subscribed, with the necessary information mentioned earlier?

I will post an update with code later, for now, I just need help with query and guidance where to look in the database tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution (not saying that it's the best, but for me, it solved the problem that I had).

**Code in function.php (WP child theme)**

```
add_action('init','getWPuser');
function getWPuser(){
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
return $current_user;
}
```

**Custom website**

Code in my custom site that needs information about the user.

```
require_once '../wp-load.php';
require_once '../wp-content/themes/h-code-child/functions.php';
require_once '../wp-includes/pluggable.php';
require_once '../wp-blog-header.php';
$current_user = getWPuser();
```

Saving user ID information.

```
$logged_user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

Checking on specific subscription if it's *active*.

```
$has_free = wcs_user_has_subscription( $logged_user_id, $product_id, 'active' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant is you want to access the Wordpress/Woocommerce Subscriptions API from a PHP file within your Wordpress installation. To do this I think the following will help:

1. Create a folder in wp-content/plugins called woocommerce-subscriptions-status-checker
2. Create a file called woocommerce-subscriptions-status-checker.php inside the above new folder.
3. Add this code in the file:

```
/* 
Plugin Name: Woocommerce Subscriptions Status Checker
Plugin URI: http://www.XXXXXX.com
Description: XXXXXXXXX
Author: XXXXXX
Version: 2.0 
Author URI: http://www.XXXXX.com
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
  exit;
}

class WC_Subscriptions_Status_Checker {

  function __construct() {

    // Avoids the function firing if we are in wp-admin backend
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
      // Fires on every page load after WordPress, all plugins, and the theme are fully loaded and instantiated
      add_action( 'wp-loaded', array( $this, 'check_current_user' ) );
    }
  }


  function check_current_user() {

    // Check if user is even logged in, if not exit
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    $current_user   = wp_get_current_user(); // get current WP_User
    $user_id    = $current_user->ID; // get user id

    $is_subscription = wcs_user_has_subscription( $user_id ); // check if user has subscription
    if ( $is_subscription )
    {
      $subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions( $user_id ); // get array of all subscriptions

      // Check if there is one subscription or multiple subscriptions per user
      if ( count( $subscriptions ) > 1 ) {

        // Example if you wanted to loop through all subscriptions, in the case of the user having multiple subscriptions
        foreach ( $subscriptions as $sub_id => $subscription ) {
          if ( $subscription->get_status() == 'active' ) {
            // Do something
          }
        }
      } else { // Only 1 subscription

        $subscription  = reset( $subscriptions ); // gets first and only value
        if ( $subscription->get_status() == 'active' ) {
            // Do something
          }
      }
    }

  }
}
new WC_Subscriptions_Status_Checker();
```

Visit the plugins section of wp-admin and Activate your new plugin.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply. My subscription plan will be monthly or annual. I  had in mind that I will check the subscription status every time a user login and visits the site?! I copied your code and test it. I get a list of active subscriptions. $post->ID displays ID of active subscription. How can I limit results to one user and for current subscription status, if I have the ID of a logged-in user?

Comment: Hi, you will definitely want to do that in a plugin then. I will edit the answer to show you how.

Comment: @Tyler is it possible to get payment gateway details of the customer. Or is it possible to make customer autopay from your plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Woocommerce REST API.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Basically, Woocommerce provide a restful API to access the data and interact with the ecommerce system outside of the traditional woocommerce workflow.